# How to understand `(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))`?

Tags: scroll, emacs, mousewheel

I copied this from somewhere, and it works well for scrolling one line at a time.

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1))) ;; one line at a time
```

However, I don't understand the meaning of  `'(1 ((shift) . 1)` here.
What does the `shift` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any variable in Emacs, use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `mouse-wheel-scroll-amount` to learn about it.

In this instance I see:

> mouse-wheel-scroll-amount is a variable defined in ‘mwheel.el’.
>   Its value is (5 ((shift) . 1) ((control)))
>
> Documentation:
>   Amount to scroll windows by when spinning the mouse wheel.
>   This is an alist **mapping the modifier key to the amount to scroll** when
>   the wheel is moved with the modifier key depressed.
>   Elements of the list have the form (MODIFIERS . AMOUNT) or just AMOUNT if
>   MODIFIERS is nil.
>
> AMOUNT should be the number of lines to scroll, or nil for near full
>   screen.  It can also be a floating point number, specifying the fraction of
>   a full screen to scroll.  A near full screen is ‘next-screen-context-lines’
>   less than a full screen.

Which is slightly technical, but is telling me that Emacs will scroll 5 lines at a time when I use the mouse wheel by default; but just 1 line at a time when I am holding <kbd>shift</kbd>; and if I am holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> then it will scroll something close to a full screen at a time -- as `((control))` is the same thing as `((control) . nil)`.

The behaviour of:

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))
```

is therefore equivalent to simply

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1))
```

as in the latter case, there are no overrides for modifier keys.